# Ошибка в Ubuntu 16.04 из-за смены прав root - Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

Установил рядом с Windows 10 на одном диске Ubuntu 16.04. И все работало хорошо, пока я своими кривыми руками не залез.

В общем началось все с того, что при работе в Ubuntu любой вновь создаваемый файл (не важно я его создавал, или он создавался при установке какого-то ПО) имел ограниченные права доступа, только на чтение.

И по этому мне приходилось постоянно менять права в каждой папке которая только что создавалась. После установки программы приходилось идти в ее директорию и менять права.

Не знаю почему так происходило, может ОС встала криво или настройки такие по дефолту были, в общем не знаю. И все кроме этого работало.

Но мне это надоело в один прекрасный момент и я взял, зашел в корневую директорию своей папки `/home`, открыл там терминал и ввел команду

```
sudo chown root:root -R *
```

(вместо root свои данные).

Я думал, что это сделает меня владельцем всей системы и мне не нужно будет вручную менять права доступа для всех вновь устанавливаемых файлов. И вот тут-то все и началось....

Теперь при каждой загрузке Ubuntu, при каждом вхождении в систему, не важно после включения компа или после перезагрузки мне обязательно нужно выполнять команду

```
fsck /dev/sda6
```

иначе никак, без этого система не грузится. Загрузка по дефолту ничего не дает, только так. Но это полбеды, потому что после этого многие файлы теряются, и некоторые программы работают некорректно. Т.е. вошел, установил что-то/скачал, поработал, вышел. Загрузился, то, что установил или скачал в предыдущий сеанс пропало или работает некорректно...

Я сохранил файлы, снес систему, отформатировал диск, установил Ubuntu заново... и вуа-ля при каждой загрузке мне все равно нужно писать `fsck /dev/sda6/`... в общем не помогло.

Что делать не знаю, может кто подскажет?

Comment: Может, у вас жесткий диск посыпался и вместо написания таких портянок нужно срочно бежать в магазин за новым?

Comment: Ну пока я не залез и не поменял права доступа все ведь работало хорошо. Мог диск посыпаться из-за смены прав? Тем более Win стоит на этом же диске и работает корректно. Ладно, попробую сделать диагностику диска какой нибудь утилитой. Спасибо

Comment: "...снес систему, отформатировал диск, установил Ubuntu заново... и вуа-ля при каждой загрузке мне все равно нужно..." - если бы вы действительно отформатировали диск, то не было бы никакого вуа-ля.

Comment: Что это значит?)  вы хотите сказать, что я его не отформатировал?)) нет, перед установкой отформатировал

Comment: Или вы его всё-таки не отформатировали, или смена прав совершенно случайно совпало с поломкой диска — вообще, смена прав никак не может быть связана с fsck :)

Comment: Совершенно точно отформатировал. Приверил утилитой...   Действительно смена прав совпала с поломкой. Пишет, что скоро ему кранты, состояние критическое

Comment: Систему то ты снес, а файловые системы переразбивал? Если нет - попробуй ;)